# Doubt on Processing Power

Tags: arduino-mega, hardware

The datasheet of arduino mega claimed that the board has 16Mhz processing power. But the question that doubt me is what would happen to the board if the board has no enough processing power.

For example,  if the board is used in an application that involves a lot of calculation in each loop. Would it stall the board?

Personally, i think the board would just give slower response instead of stalling the board. It was due request is done in sequential method in the code. Therefore it would not accumulate up the request until stalling the device like PC and I think it would be just at most an arduino which is always busy.

Is it what would happen if the board has no enough processing power?

Comment: The Arduino doesn't multi-task like your PC does. How it behaves is entirely dependent on how you write your sketch. If you write it such that it gets stuck for long periods processing and not responding to input, then that's what it'll do. If you write it to respond to input rapidly and do processing in small chunks in between, it'll do that. Does that answer your question or help understand the situation better?

Answer (score 1):

Processing Power is a bit of a misnomer. Clock Frequency is a better description.

In general one assembly instruction gets executed each clock cycle. That means approximately 16 million instructions per second (there are a couple that take more than 1).

Your C program gets compiled into those instructions and executed at 16 million instructions per second.

If your routine is 16 million instructions long (when loops are unrolled) then it will take 1 second to execute.

Unlike a PC, which is constantly switching between tasks, an Arduino does only one thing, and that is the one thing you programmed it to do. Because of that execution time is predictable. If it took 1 second to execute today it will take 1 second tomorrow,  and 1 second next week.